# Split string based on spaces and read that in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2-pipe

I am creating a pipe in angular2 where I want to split the string on white spaces and later on read it as an array.

```
let stringToSplit = "abc def ghi";
StringToSplit.split(" ");
console.log(stringToSplit[0]);
```

When I log this, I always get "a" as output. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: I hope you understand why you always got "a" by now.

Comment: it is not assigning value to same string. And if also it will do, it will be like assigning string[] in string

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Made a few changes:

`let stringToSplit = "abc def ghi";
let x = stringToSplit.split(" ");
console.log(x[0]);`

The [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method returns an array. Instead of using its result, you are getting the first element of the original string.

Comment: Wonderful. Glad to help.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as completed if it solved your problem. It will help others as well.

Comment: Thanks @RaduCojocari

Comment: Thank @Radu Cojocari,  split()  function return an array

Answer (score 5):

```
let stringToSplit = "abc def ghi";
StringToSplit.split(" ");
console.log(stringToSplit[0]);
```

First, `stringToSplit` and `StringToSplit` are not the same. JS is case sensitive. Also you dont save result of `StringToSplit.split(" ")` anywhere and then you just output the first character of the string `stringToSplit` which is `a`. You could do like this:

```js
    let stringToSplit = "abc def ghi";
    console.log(stringToSplit.split(" ")[0]); // stringToSplit.split(" ") returns array and then we take the first element of the array with [0]
```

PS. also it is more about JavaScript than TypeScript or Angular.

Comment: This is a much clearer answer. At least you explained what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i created this npm package for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/search-string-eerg

```
    function customSearch(s, p) {
      let x = p.split(" ");
        var find = true;
        for (var partIndex in x) {
    if (s.toLowerCase().indexOf(x[partIndex]) > -1) {
      // Let this item feature in the result set only if other parts of the
      // query have been found too
      find = find && true;
    } else {
      // Even if a single part of the query was not found, this item
      // should not feature in the results
      find = false;
    }
     }
     return find;
}
```